# ¿Por qué se usa en unos sitios "centavo" y en otros "céntimo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

He visto que

[**Céntimo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8FSfgZn)
1. adj. centésimo (‖ que es una de las cien partes de un todo).
2. m. En algunos países, moneda, acuñada o no, que vale la centésima parte de la unidad monetaria.

[**Centavo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8ENeMRj)
1. adj. centésimo (‖ que es una de las cien partes de un todo).
2. m. En algunos países, moneda que vale la centésima parte de la unidad monetaria.

Siendo las definiciones iguales, ¿por qué en unos países se utiliza "centavo" y en otros "céntimo"?

Answer (score 4):

Porque son sinónimos.

Del latín *centesimus* nos llega `centésimo` y, a través del francés *centime*, `céntimo`.

De `ciento` y [`avo`](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4adXPPv) se forma `centavo`, de acuerdo con la manera regular de formar números fraccionarios (número cardinal + `avo`).

Hoy en día, `céntimo` y `centavo` en general ya no se usan como fracciones. De todas maneras, a la hora de elegir una denominación para la centésima parte de la moneda, da lo mismo cualquiera de las tres, porque todas tienen el mismo significado (1/100 de la unidad monetaria).

Comment: `Hoy en día, céntimo y centavo en general ya no se usan como fracciones.` Esta afirmación no es cierta. Puesto que como me revates a mi, hay sitios donde se usa tanto uno como otro. Incluso centésimos. Por otra parte, solo aludes al origen de la palabra y no ofreces razón por la que unos países usan un termino u otro.

Comment: ¿Qué sitios? Sobre lo otro: simplemente digo que no hay una razón común de fondo para que se haya elegido un término u otro. Por ejemplo, Chile usó "centavo" desde la época de la colonia, cambió a "centésimo" en 1960, volvió a "centavo" en 1975. En este caso quizás haya sido para diferenciarse de la moneda anterior. En otros sería porque les sonaba mejor, etc... No creo que haya que buscar más lejos que "lo que les pareció en el momento".

Comment: Ese argumento es tan pobre como el mío pues. Y es más, es tan abierto a interpretaciones, que podría usarse como respuesta por defecto para cualquier pregunta de este site.

Answer (score 3):

El uso de uno u otro depende más de la moneda en sí que de otras razones. El DPD lo deja más o menos claro para el euro: https://www.rae.es/dpd/centavo

Podemos ver que otros países eligen una denominación concreta para la centésima parte de su moneda. Por ejemplo, la centésima parte de un boliviano es "centavo" y no "céntimo". Básicamente porque lo pone en el artículo 1 de la su ley: https://www.lexivox.org/norms/BO-L-901.html

El Euro en españa se divide en céntimos, y esa es su denominación oficial: https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-1998-29216&p=20121031&tn=1#a3

Por otra parte, la denominación de la centésima parte de una libra esterlina (*pounds*) no es ni céntimos de libra ni de centavos de libra, sino peniques: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penique

Comment: Buena documentación, gracias

Answer (score 3):

Según mis pesquisas, centavo es una palabra española que deriva del latin. Mientras que, céntimo, es una palabra española que deriva del francés. En todo el territorio americano, la palabra dominante es centavo, por influencia del español. Mientras que, en España, lo es céntimo por influencia de los borbones, que nunca dejaron de sentirse franceses, y, nosotros, de sentirnos genuflexos en lugar de defender lo propio ante el extraño.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que el uso de uno u otro depende de la moneda, más que del país. Lo he encontrado buscando por la tercera forma [Centésimo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent%C3%A9simo_(fracci%C3%B3n)). Aunque tiene que haber influencia del idioma porque la fracción del Euro es **cent** (centavo, como el dólar), pero en España usamos "céntimo".

Lo mismo pasa en otras regiones latinoamericanas, donde parece predominar *centavos*. Tal vez por influencia (¿cultural, política, económica?) de Norteamérica.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver la influencia norteamericana con el predominio de "centavos"? ¿Podrías desarrollar un poco más la idea? Porque no le veo mucho sentido.

Comment: Si a la influencia a la que está sometido Latinoamérica respecto a Norteamerica no te parece razonable, poco puedo explicar. Para empezar esta el idioma, el comercio, la influencia cultural a través de películas (que la mayoría no se doblan como en España), música, tv,... Aquí el influjo norteamericano solo hace poco más de una década que empezo a tener efectos notorios. Antes del Euro, Norteamerica era lo que se veía en las pelis y encima dobladas. Y aquí se doblaba TODO. Hasta los nombres propios. Las influencias culturales entre países o regiones fronterizas pueden ser de muchas naturalezas

Comment: Pregunto sobre el caso específico de "centavos". ¿O la idea que querés dar es que todo lo que no se hace como en España es automáticamente por influencia norteamericana?

Comment: Fíjate en el enlace que hay en mi respuesta. Fíjate en los países de esas latitudes que usan "centavos" y que tienen en común. Luego las que usan céntimos. Eso no puede ser casualidad. Y si buscas los hechos concretos que llevo a un grupo de personas reunidas en una sala,  a usar la fracción "centavo" o "céntimos", me temo que va a ser complicado. Y fíjate que la respuesta que doy no es categórica. *Tal vez...*. Lo que si te puedo asegurar ds que en España, centavo no se usa y que se debe a que aquí lo traducimos todo, tb. En el resto de Europa si es más común "cent".

Comment: Y eso se debe a que en España, el inglés como idioma ha tenido una influencia marginal durante muchísimo tiempo. Cosa que ha cambiado desde que entramos en la CE. Y ha tenido mayor influjo desde que la CEE introdujo el Euro y la libre circulación por Europa. Antes de eso, el inglés solo lo hablaban los turistas.

Comment: _“Lo que sí te puedo asegurar es que en España, centavo no se usa y que se debe a que aquí lo traducimos todo”_  ¿Es posible que creas que "centavo" es una palabra inglesa? (¿!)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @angus. En Colombia se llaman centavos desde 1810. No creo que por influencia norteamericana ni del inglés. Esta respuesta es completamente especulativa.

Comment: No, centavo por raíz "ciento" y esta tiene por su origen latin "cientum". No se trata de quien acuña la palabra, sino de quien la divulga y en que medida. [Dolar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%B3lar). en este link podemos ver como el Dolar tiene una enorma influencia en muchos paises de latinoamérica. En algunos hasta se acepta. Otros lo han adoptado. Pero como ya dije, mi respuesta no es categórica. Porqué hay paises que adoptan el dolar o lo aceptan y siguen usando la expresión "céntimos" pero son menos que los casos anteriores.

Comment: @Laiv: creo que en España, en tiempos de las pesetas (la moneda anterior al euro) había monedas fraccionarias llamadas "céntimos" (100 céntimos = 1 peseta), por lo que al cambiarse al euro parece lógico que para las fracciones de euro se siguiera utilizando "céntimos"  en vez de "cent"

Comment: _Cent_ no es _centavo_, sino _cent_: Moneda que vale la centésima parte de un euro. [[DLE](https://dle.rae.es/cent)]

Comment: El porqué no lo sé, pero fundéu recoge que es preferible usar céntimos para el euro y centavos para el dólar. Para el resto de monedas no especifica nada. https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/centavo-centimo/ . Además, sin haber indagado más, el dpd especifica que depende más bien de la moneda en sí que otra cosa. https://www.rae.es/dpd/centavo

Answer (score 1):

el centavo se usa en países donde usen el dólar y céntimos para el resto de los países, en el caso de los países donde usen 2 monedas legales donde incluyan el dólar usan centavos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuetas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent%C3%A9simo_(fracci%C3%B3n_monetaria) Los centavos se usan en todos los países menos Venezuela, Costa Rica, España, Paraguay, Uruguay, Perú y Panamá, donde tienen o céntimos o centésimos.